# Why doesn't the F# Set implement ISet<T>?

Tags: .net, f#, interface, set

The .NET Framework is adding an `ISet<T>` interface with the 4.0 release. In the same release, F# is being added as a first-class language. F# provides an immutable `Set<'T>` class.

It would seem logical to me that the immutable set provided would implement the `ISet<T>` interface, but it doesn't. Does anyone know why?

My guess is that they didn't want to implement an interface intended to be mutable, but I don't think this explanation holds up. After all, their `Map<'Key, 'Value>` class implements `IDictionary`, which is mutable. And there are examples elsewhere in the framework of classes implementing interfaces that are only partially appropriate.

My other thought is that `ISet<T>` is new, so maybe they didn't get around to it. But that seems kind of thin.

Does the fact that `ISet<T>` is generic (v. `IDictionary`, which is not) have anything to do with it?

Any thoughts on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: In the .NET framework itself, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`, which is a mutable interface.

Comment: @Steven Right, that's an example of a framework class implementing an interface that isn't totally appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Offhand I don't think *I* was previously aware of `ISet`.  (Actually I looked back through old email, and found one mention of BCL plans for it--from 2008--but that was it.  So I think it wasn't on our radar.)

That said, F# strives to be source-compatible between its .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 bits, to the point of back-porting .NET 4.0 entities into FSharp.Core.dll version 2.0.  For example, The 2.0 FSharp.Core contains `System.Tuple`, `System.BigInteger`, `System.Threading.CancelationTokenSource` (part of the async programming model), etc., and `ISet` would potentially be another bit of work to back-port (it's unclear to me if it would be 'necessary' to port it, though).

I'll file an issue to have a look, though it may be moot at this point in time.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't realize there was a drive to keep F# source-compatible across frameworks. Just curious, but what is the reasoning behind this? Is the official stance that .NET 4.0 does not contain a "new" version of F#, but rather an official, first-class packaging of F# as it exists today?

Answer (score 6):

Since no one else is jumping in, I'll add my speculation.  First of all, the majority of the `IDictionary<'k,'v>` interface still makes sense for an immutable dictionary; it's really only adding or removing individual elements that won't work.  Secondly, there's a decent amount of code that has already been written which relies on `IDictionary`, so being able to use F# values with that code is a nice plus.

On the other hand, several of `ISet<'t>`'s methods require mutation, including not just adding individual elements, but also several set mutating operators such as union and intersection.  Additionally, many set use cases are already subsumed by the `IEnumerable<'t>` interface - I think that it will be relatively rare for people to rely on `ISet<'t>` implementations for immutable set based code.

I don't think that genericity has anything to do with it - note that despite the MSDN documentation, F# maps implement the generic `IDictionary` interface, not the non-generic one.

Comment: This sounds plausible. Still, it's frustrating if true. It seems like a mistake to me to include all those interface methods that imply the mutability of the implementing class. (Likewise, I think it would be a mistake to include methods implying the class should be _immutable_.) It would be nice if `ISet<T>` included only "read" members. I think the interface as-is is too opinionated, and now I _still_ don't really have a way to communicate simply that "this is a collection of unique items." (At least so far as F# interop is concerned.)

Comment: Looks like not quite the majority: by my count, only five of the 11 proper members of `ISet<T>` require mutation. If you include inherited members from `ICollection<T>`, it becomes eight of 18. (And of these, at least `void Add(T item)` will probably be implemented explicitly.)

Comment: I was thinking about writing a similar answer, but then I looked at the `ISet<T>` interface and found out that it has quite a few operations that can still be implemented (namely `SetEquals`, `IsSubsetOf`, `IsSupersetOf`, `Overlaps`, `IsProperSubsetOf`, `IsProperSupersetOf`), maybe it's fewer than `IDictionary`, but still quite a few... Another reasoning may be that there are no .NET methods that would take `ISet<T>`, so there is no application-driven reason for implementing it (I guess there may be some good use case for `IDictionary`).

Comment: @Tomas That's true, but it seems to me that _not_ implementing it introduces some friction for anyone writing new code. For example, I want to define some interfaces that pass around sets (not to modify, just to query against). This adds friction to F# consumers of my code, so now it almost makes more sense just to fall back to `IEnumerable<T>` for my interface. Kind of a bummer, I was really excited about the addition of this interface to the framework. It seems like this will inhibit adoption a little bit.

Comment: @Sean: I agree, I guess that .NET BCL should really include a better set of interfaces to represent collections, sets, dictionaries and their immutable versions, etc. This is probably hard to do, given the .NET 1 legacy that we have to live with.

Comment: @Sean - you're right, not quite a majority, I'll update my post.